# Update UICollectionView Width on Device Rotate in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have custom keyboard with a UICollectionView. The cells do not have a defined size. When rotating the device from portrait to landscape the keyboard resizes appropriately but the UICollectionView stays at the original width.

What is the best way to tackle updating the width to expand to the full available with? How can I update the constraints to the available space?

The UICollectionView is created programmatically and I'm not using a storyboard to implement AutoLayout that way.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)

    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)

    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self

    collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: kbReuseIdentifier)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

    self.view.addSubview(collectionView)

    let collectionViewBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.collectionView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -40.0)
    let collectionViewTopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.collectionView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 10)
    let collectionViewLeftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.collectionView, attribute: .LeadingMargin, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .LeadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    let collectionViewRightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.collectionView, attribute: .TrailingMargin, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .TrailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)


    self.view.addConstraints([collectionViewBottomConstraint, collectionViewTopConstraint, collectionViewRightConstraint, collectionViewLeftConstraint])


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol on your view controller.

On `viewDidLoad`, register for orientation changed notifications:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "orientationDidChange:", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

Don't forget to remove the observer when the viewController is closed:

```
deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

When the orientation changes, tell the collectionView to update the layout:

```
func orientationDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

Finally, implement the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol method. On this method you can calculate the size for your collection view cells as needed, by referencing the collectionView frame width or the device screen size:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // Leave 10px margin on each side, plus 10px between columns
    let columns = 2
    let margings = 20 + 10 * (columns - 1)
    let width = (collectionView.frame.size.width - margings) / columns
    let height = width // square cells
    return CGSizeMake(width, height)
}
```

In my case, I want the cells to always be proportional to the portrait screen ratio. Also I have a variable number of columns, but that might not be your case.

Comment: I've implemented your code and it doesn't appear to work.

There is an error with self.columns stating that KeyboardViewController has no member "columns" (I know what it means).

In addition where does screenRatio get set?

I set static values for width, height, and margin and nothing gets resized.

Comment: Both screenRatio and columns are properties I set on my viewController, I've updated the response to remove those variables.

Comment: You can also adjust the margins as needed, or remove them completely.

Comment: This solution works great and should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding `updateViewConstraints`, check what is the current orientation with `UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation`/`UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation` and update the `constant` of certain constraints in your `NSAutoLayout` logic.